# Asp.net MVC base controller with constructor injection and MEF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, mef, constructor-injection

I have a base controller class that exposes some logging functionality to it's child classes. This logging dependency is constructor injected. To provide some simplified code this is how it all looks like:

```
public abstract class LogControllerBase : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger logger = null;

    protected LogControllerBase(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

My child controllers also have their own dependencies hence they look something like this:

```
public class SomeController : LogControllerBase
{
    private readonly IService service = null;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SomeController(ILogger logger, IService service)
        : base(logger)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

I'm using these constructors to make it easy to do dependency injection in my unit tests but in production all composition is (should be) done by MEF. I'm using my custom controller factory class that uses MEF to instantiate controllers.

**To sum it up:**

1. I have a base abstract controller class that has its own dependencies
2. I have descendant controllers that use importing to get their parameters injected by MEF (that is their dependencies as well as base class' ones)
3. Unit tests don't use MEF so mocks are injected to constructor parameters

### The problem

This all holds water to me, but MEF thinks differently. When I compile and run this code I get this exception:

> **GetExportedValue cannot be called before prerequisite import 'SomeController..ctor (Parameter="logger", ContractName="ILogger")' has been set.**

All interface types that are used as constructor parameters have attribute `InheritedExport` set on them and also have concrete implementations, so it should work as expected.

### Working alternative which isn't the same

When I try an alternative approach by doing imports directly on those private fields everything seems to work just fine.

```
public abstract class LogControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    [Import]
    private ILogger logger = null;

    protected LogControllerBase() { }
}

public class SomeController : LogControllerBase
{
    [Import]
    private IService service = null;

    public SomeController() { }
}
```

So this works but it's not the same... I could add constructors here for dependency injection, but then I'd have two sets of constructors and when doing unit tests one may use the parameterless constructor which would of course be wrong because no dependencies would get set. Not real ones nor mocks.

### Question

How can I convince MEF to create my controllers by injecting concrete implementations in constructor by setting dependency injection constructor as `ImportingConstructor`?

Comment: @Steven: Unfortunately that's not possible because MEF is internal policy set by a higher library that **must** be used in my web application. And to tell you the truth considering other requirements related to this app I'd choose MEF myself as well. There are other benefits to it that can't be easily done with other *statically* defined DI containers.

Comment: I really can't imagine that there is not much you cannot do with other containers. In fact, almost all other containers are much faster and much feature rich. The only thing I think MEF shines in, is handling plugin architectures, where the plugins run in different app domains (as VS does).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: No go, because A library I have to use uses MEF. So that's not really a solution. It may be a healthy suggestion but I can't take it. Thanks anyway Darin.

Comment: I understand this very well. That's why I didn't post it as answer. It was more as an incitation for you to talk to the people responsible for taking those design decisions in the company you are working for. Who knows, they might even listen to you :-)

Comment: AFAIK MEF plugins run in the same AppDomain.  If VS plugins run in a different AppDomain, then that's not a feature of MEF.  I think MAF is the one that does the AppDomain separation.

Comment: I notice that `LogControllerBase` inherits `ControllerBase` and not `Controller`  anything interesting going on there?

Comment: @JimCounts: No no. It's just a typo. This is a super simplified example. It actually inherits from a different controller that inherits from `Controller` but it has no relevant code in it... Let me change my code... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: This particular library has been in development for well over a year. Just because my controllers can't be instantiated won't cut it... They'd need some more firm arguments I suppose. My statement *change MEF with something else* would turn out quite lame. And to tell you the truth MEF isn't a bad tool in this scenario, because we are using 1-many mappings here from exports to concretes with filtered selections. MEF does this brilliantly. I might write a blog post (after those 5 that are still awaiting) related to this.

Comment: Just a sidenote, we've done a lot of work recently to provide a streamlined MEF experience in these scenarios via the Microsoft.Composition package being released via NuGet: http://mef.codeplex.com/documentation - hopefully providing a best-of-both-worlds approach :)

Comment: Can you please add some details so that we can reproduce the issue locally? How are the controllers being exported? If you're able to attach a minimal repro to the CodePlex issue that would be a huge help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to threading, as MEF containers are not constructed as thread-safe by default. In your constructor for your container, try enabling thread-safety:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
```

Comment: I can see a statement in the library that I have to use. And it uses `false` for `isThreadSafe`. So what can I do now?

Comment: Can't you recompile the library with `isThreadSafe` set to `true`? If not, I would bring this up with the library author.